# How to do multiplication (capital pi) in WolframAlpha?

Tags: soft-question, products, infinite-product, wolfram-alpha

How do i ask this in WolframAlpha:

$$\prod_{i=0}^{i=10} \sin{(i)}$$

I used $\text{product}(...)$ and $\text{multiply}(...)$ or even $\text{multiplication}(...)$ but they don't seem to work.

I am actually not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question but Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: @TravisJ that will cause problems when some multiplicands are negative

Comment: @GFauxPas, good point hadn't thought of that.  Thanks.

Comment: @TravisJ don't delete your comment! Your idea will still work in many cases!

Comment: @GFauxPas, sure, amended comment: provided that the multiplicands are positive, then $\prod_{i} a_{i} = e^{\sum_{i}\ln(a_{i})}$... so multiplication can be recast as a sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For example:** `product (1)/n, n=1..10`

Computation [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product%20%281%29%2Fn%2C%20n%3D1..10).

Comment: Or http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B10%7D+sin%28i%29

Comment: @SimonS Latex?? Wow!!

Comment: I only recently discovered that you could use Latex (or Latex-like) syntax with WA. It's a great feature.

Answer (score 1):

As anakhronizein wrote

> product sin (k), k=0..10

The trick lies in the main page, where you find on the right side the bar "Example". If you click it, you find pretty much everything. For example. the answer to your question can be found by then choosing "Mathematics", and finally "Calculus & Analysis". I hope it helps for the future!

Comment: Ah...Thanks! needed it!